# Scrapy sqmllinkextractor rule changes urls

Tags: python, regex, scrapy

I'm trying to build a webcrawler spider using Scrapy and I've set up a Rule for the links I want my crawler to pick up using a regex:

```
rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow='http\:\/\/www\.cartelera\.com\.uy\/apeliculafunciones\.aspx\?[^"]*1&29'), 'parse_loly', follow=True, ),)
```

I checked the regex and it works and it matches the links I want the spider to crawl, but when I ran the program, the spider found no items and with a little checking I found out that while the regex matches the items correctly, when the spider goes to crawl the page the url it uses is different than it should be.

For example, the spider should match and crawl urls such as

```
http://www.cartelera.com.uy/apeliculafunciones.aspx?7242&&CINE&OBRA&-1&29
http://www.cartelera.com.uy/apeliculafunciones.aspx?10704&&CINE&OBRA&-1&29
http://www.cartelera.com.uy/apeliculafunciones.aspx?10697&&CINE&OBRA&-1&29
```

But the urls scrapy crawls  come out like

```
http://www.cartelera.com.uy/apeliculafunciones.aspx?-1=&29=&7242=&CINE=&OBRA=
http://www.cartelera.com.uy/apeliculafunciones.aspx?-1=&29=&10704=&CINE=&OBRA=
http://www.cartelera.com.uy/apeliculafunciones.aspx?-1=&29=&10697=&CINE=&OBRA=
```

These urls lead to error pages so, obviously, no items are found.

There are no error messages
Why is this happening and how do I avoid it?

Pasting my class code below

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'cartelera'
    allowed_domains = ["www.cartelera.com.uy"]
    start_urls = ["http://www2.cartelera.com.uy/apeliculafunciones.aspx?,,PELICULAS,OBRA,0,26"]

    rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow='http\:\/\/www\.cartelera\.com\.uy\/apeliculafunciones\.aspx\?[^"]*1&29'), 'parse_loly', follow=True, ),)

##simple debugging method to output and check the crawled urls
def parse_loly(self, response):
print '%s' % response.url
return
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

those urls are not standard, you can overcome this by telling sgml extractor not to canonicalize them, like:

```
SgmlLinkExtractor(allow='http...', canonicalize=False)
```

here's how you work with scrapy shell to find that out:

```
$ scrapy shell "http://www2.cartelera.com.uy/apeliculafunciones.aspx?,,PELICULAS,OBRA,0,26"
...
>>> from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
>>> s = SgmlLinkExtractor(allow='http\:\/\/www\.cartelera\.com\.uy\/apeliculafunciones\.aspx\?[^"]*1&29', canonicalize=False)
>>> for link in s.extract_links(response):
...     print link
... 
Link(url='http://www.cartelera.com.uy/apeliculafunciones.aspx?10697&&CINE&OBRA&-1&29', text=u'', fragment='', nofollow=False)
Link(url='http://www.cartelera.com.uy/apeliculafunciones.aspx?10697&&CINE&OBRA&-1&29#titulosalas', text=u'aqu\xed', fragment='', nofollow=False)
Link(url='http://www.cartelera.com.uy/apeliculafunciones.aspx?10795&&CINE&OBRA&-1&29', text=u'', fragment='', nofollow=False)
...
```

Comment: Thanks, that works great and thanks for the shell testing as well!